# How to get long and lat based on a geography spatial data type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, geometry, geospatial

The issue I am having is that I am trying to get the long and lat values based on a location field, I have the geography column but I always get an error as shown below:

> Msg 403, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>    Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals equal to, type equals geography.

This is the query basically:

```
select Loc.Lat, Loc.Long  from VideoGamesLocation
where  Loc= '0xE6100000010CBFF1B56796AE4A4029A78951EA6519C0'
```

Do you guys know how to get the values for lat and long based on the above query?

Comment: That doesn't look like a GUID, and it doesn't look like a binary string.  Where did that string come from?

Comment: That is a geography spatial data type David, is the Loc field.

Comment: How does the string '0xE610000001CFDSFDS45E4A4029A78951EA6519C0' relate to a geography instance?  It's not WKT or WKB.  It's not even a hex string, as it's got `SFDS` in the middle.

Comment: There was a typo, that is the value that is stored in a greography data type field.

Comment: So basically, this part works: select Loc.Lat, Loc.Long  from VideoGamesLocation , but when I try to filter by Loc, I get the above error.

Comment: My suggestion would be to give your table a primary key that is something easier to match on. A classic identity column comes to mind. That way, you can say `where Loc = 12345` instead of some non-human meaningful hex data. The ID will be arbitrary but simple.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Then cast to `geography` and compare using [STEquals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stequals-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) or one of the other functions.  EG

```
drop table if exists VideoGamesLocation
create table VideoGamesLocation(id int, Loc geography)

DECLARE @g geography;   
SET @g = cast(0xE6100000010CBFF1B56796AE4A4029A78951EA6519C0 as geography)
insert into VideoGamesLocation(id, Loc) values (1,@g)


select Loc.Lat, Loc.Long  from VideoGamesLocation
where  1=Loc.STEquals(cast(0xE6100000010CBFF1B56796AE4A4029A78951EA6519C0 as geography))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .STEquals operator instead of = .
This function will return 1 if equality holds.

Also use cast function to convert '0xE61000..' to geography data type.

so , the sql query should be :
select Loc.Lat, Loc.Long  from VideoGamesLocation
where  1=Loc.STEquals(cast(0xE6100000010CBFF1B56796AE4A4029A78951EA6519C0 as geography))